# How to count entries in column that are separated by commas

Tags: r, count, subset

I have a column `reasons` with rows of survey respondents. Responses in `reasons` are separated by comma, so one cell in the column `reasons` would read **reason1, reason2, reason3**. I want to count entries that include reason1 (whether its the only reason listed or not). So far, I have done this

```
hair1 = read_excel('hair1.xlsx')
reason1 = data.frame(subset(hair1, reasons=='reason1'))
```

This **only** returns survey respondents that listed reason1 and not those who may have listed reason1 with other reasons as well.

`dput(head(hair1))`
structure(list(reasons = c("reason1, reason2, reason3","reason1, reason2")

Comment: Have you try `hair1 = read.excel("hair1.xlsx", sep  = ",") ` ? Can you provide the output of `str(hair1)` ?

Comment: just do `reason1 <- subset(hair1, grepl("reason1",reasons))`

Comment: ```hair1 = read_excel('hair1.xlsx', sep=",")```` returns an error that says **unused argument (sep = ",")**

Comment: How about `table(hair1$reasons)`? More specifically `table(hair1$reasons)[1]`

Comment: ```reason1 <- subset(hair1, grepl("reason1",reasons))``` returns an error that says **subet must be logical**

Comment: ```str(hair1)``` gives this Classes 'tbl'and 'data.frame': 221 obs of 1 variable: $ reasons: chr "reason1" , "reason1, reason2, reason3" "reason1" "reason1"...

Comment: Can she update? It's been closed.

Comment: @markhogue yes, you can edit the post even if it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Subset with one equal sign instead of two worked

`reason1 = data.frame(subset(hair1, reasons="reason1"))`